# To find best classification model for data

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, classification

I have data following largest extreme value distribution model, which classification model would be best for this? I'm trying to perform binary classification with predictive modeling...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to simply try with different models and see which perform better for the given dataset.
You can do it manually using Scikit-learn for example or you can use an auto-ml librairie such as [PyCaret](https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/get-started/quickstart)